# Install java inside a docker

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to install java on my docker to be able to use a node module (... yes ...)
I've been searching and I found multiple way of doing it but it always throw an error so, I'm gonna show you what I use for now

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
RUN update-alternatives --config java
RUN update-alternatives --config javac
```

switching grom java 8 to java 11 throw the same error:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/impish/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If someone could help me understand what I'm missing that could be cool !

Comment: Can you make a complete Dockerfile that shows the error you're getting? That saves us from trying to guess which base image you use.

Comment: another thing that you could do is, use the base image, without any extra additions, and you can run : `docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash -it <your image>:<version>` to enter into it, run commands until you get java working, and finally use `history` command to get the relevant commands, you could be behind a firewall, so we need to consider that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to stop the problem. The reason why I why trying to use this `RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa` is because without I was getting this error
`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

But after some research I found this way of using java inside my docker:

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1/
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
RUN update-alternatives --config java
RUN update-alternatives --config javac
```

The second line fixed the problem by creating the right folder